# What is good way to create android database

Tags: android

I am doing one android project and about to create local database using sqlite. I have read several tutorials but still confusing whats good way to create android db and I do not know why is it good to use content provider for database because those uri things make me more confusing.. can anyone recommend a good tutorial??

Also, do I have to make a class that extends **SQLiteOpenHelper** for each data table I want to use?? Let's say I need three tables in the app..

1. User
2. Address
3. Message

Then do I need to make three different SQLiteOpenHelper to manage data?? or is there a way to consolidate all of these tables and use one db instance to access and manipulate data?? 
Thanks

Comment: can you please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008528/static-database-class-to-use-with-any-activity/20052152#20052152 one. I have given answer for the same

Answer (score 0):

yes it is better to make separate classes for each function.for each function you should make a separate class like for sign up,login etc. and in each class you have to extend SQLiteOpenHelper.

[you can refer to this link.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)

a very good tutorial for SQLite is provided by the google itself [sqlite by google](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this video, usually videos help better than reading tutorials:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aui-kFuXFYE

And for your second question, you don't need to create different databases for different tables. A database can handle multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

Myself I moved to Realm.io for android. Its faster, easier , cleaner code, and you work with objects. I can help you if interested to get going with realm.

But if you would like to continue with SQLLite :

best practice is to build 1 openHelperClass.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


//Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

//Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDB";

//Tables

//Table1 + Columns
private static final String TABLE_1 = "tb1"; //Table 

private static final String KEY_TB1_1 = "tb1col1";
private static final String KEY_TB1_2 = "tb1col2";

//Table2 + Columns

private static final String TABLE_2 = "tb2";

private static final String KEY_TB2_1 = "tb2col1";
private static final String KEY_TB2_2 = "tb2col2";


//Constructor
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

//onCreate
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    //Create TB1          
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_1 + "("   + 
    KEY_TB1_1 + " TEXT, " + 
    KEY_TB1_2 + " TEXT)";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    //Create TB2          
    CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_2 + "("  + 
    KEY_TB2_1 + " TEXT, " + 
    KEY_TB2_2 + " TEXT)";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_1);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_2);

    onCreate(db);

}
}
```

and you go on from here creating methods to add,delete,update data from the tables.